# zipping a list of lists according to index?

Tags: python-2.7, indexing, zip, list-comprehension

How can I use `zip` to zip a list of lists according to index?

```
a = [i for i in "four"]
b = [i for i in "help"]
c = [i for i in "stak"]
k = [a,b,c]

print zip(a,b,c)
print zip(k)
```

`zip(a,b,c)` prints out `[('f', 'h', 's'), ('o', 'e', 't'), ('u', 'l', 'a'), ('r', 'p', 'k')]`

This is what I need.

However `zip(k)` prints out `[(['f', 'o', 'u', 'r'],), (['h', 'e', 'l', 'p'],), (['s', 't', 'a', 'k'],)]`

This doesn't help at all.

Is there any way to "**break up**" a list int it's individual pieces for the zip function?

I need the list k, this is a simplified example, k would have an unknown amount of lists for where i'm using it.

Comment: If `zip(a,b,c)` gives you what you need, then... what's your question?

Comment: For where I'm using it, I *need* to do zip(k). The length of k is unknown im ny situation, this is just an example. I can't simply do zip(a,b,c,d,e,...NaN, NaN)

Comment: It does not work with python 3.4 in windows :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code:

`zip(*[lists...])`

You can put in any number of lists in there (can easily be generated using list comprehension)

Comment: `*list` is the general syntax for list unpacking in Python. Works with function parameters, too, which is why you see things like `*args`.

Comment: An interesting use case of `*` is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25073064/python-3-print-generator#25073064