# python 3 print generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, generator

There is a problem when i deal with print() function(Python 3).

When I'm looking for sum of a series I may use the following code pattern:

```
>>> sum(i for i in range(101))
```

But when I tend to check the series that I had made: (I choose print() and assume it will print out line by line)

```
>>> print(i for i in range(101))
```

It turns out become a generator object without value return. So I have to used list() for series checking. Is that a flaw in print function?

PS: The above written is an example to form a generator, not the simplest form for natural series but the bone structure for complex series. In order for convenience in series values checking, I am looking for a way to print out each value line by line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`sum` takes an iterable of things to add up, while `print` takes separate arguments to print. If you want to feed all the generator's items to `print` separately, use `*` notation:

```
print(*(i for i in range(1, 101)))
```

You don't actually need the generator in either case, though:

```
sum(range(1, 101))
print(*range(1, 101))
```

If you want them on separate lines, you're expecting the behavior of multiple individual calls to `print`, which means you're expecting the behavior of a regular loop:

```
for item in generator_or_range_or_whatever:
    print(item)
```

though you also have the option of specifying `'\n'` as an item separator:

```
print(*generator_or_range_or_whatever, sep='\n')
```

Comment: This is interesting because there is no analogous behavior to this with python2.x's print statement as far as I can see.  +1 from me.

Comment: @mgilson: Well, there's always `from __future__ import print_function`, but with the statement version, there's nothing analogous.

Comment: Yes -- I did think of that... My point was more that this is an interesting use-case for a print function that you can't get with a print statement.

Comment: That's the natural number series, I tend to use it to perform more complex series like x**x**-1 in definite range, thus I have to verify values in series. Thanks for the simplification though.

Comment: So I have to unpack the generated object in order to view them in print()? No ways to view them line by line?

Comment: @nobody: If you want to view them line by line, you just want a regular `for` loop.

Comment: If you want them line by line, you can also print them at once and set the `sep` keyword argument to `'\n'`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I keep forgetting that's an option.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for your explanation, case solved.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That's viable and perfect output, thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2357112 The first print() lack of a ')', I can't edit it for you. The generator needs extra '()' in print function, range() doesn't need.

Comment: @nobody: Whoops, mismatched those. Thanks.

Comment: print(*(generator)_or_range_or_whatever, sep='\n'), you're welcome @user2357112

Comment: @nobody: The lack of parentheses there was deliberate, as `generator_or_range_or_whatever` was meant to have the structure of a Python identifier. I suppose we'll just say it's a stylistic difference.

Comment: Sorry about that, thank you very much for clear explanation and instruction. @user2357112

Answer (score 1):

This behavior isn't too much different than on python2.x:

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>> print (i*i for i in range(30))
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x10c034a50>
```

Generally speaking, if you want to actually know the items, a list might be easiest (it just requires the addition of a couple square brackets:

```
print [i*i for i in range(30)]
```

or on python3.x:

```
print([i*i for i in range(30)])
```

Comment: Can I just observe that `[i for i in range(30)]` IS `range(30)`, and writing it is similar to writing `if x>3 == True:`. So you xould have written `print range(30)` and `print(range(30))`

Comment: @holdenweb `print([range(20)])` too returns a list of generator object. So the only solution is to expand and write `for i in ..`

Comment: @holdenweb this again is a difference between 2.x and 3.x. 2.x's `range` is a function that creates lists; 3.x's `range` is a class similar to 2.x `xrange` but with a little extra functionality.

Comment: Correct. The simplest way to produce a list from a generator is to apply the `list()` built-in. Applying it to a list bears the cost of creating a duplicate list, but that's no worse than iterating over it in an unnecessary comprehension. Of course, styles vary ...

Comment: @mgilson thanks for reply and don't bother about the iteration issue as I intend to show a generator case by any mean(as "simple better than complex" is the Zen of Python), I would rather give a simple example than "complex to fit simplest" example.

Comment: @holdenweb -- That's true. `[i for i in ...]` is generally not something you want to be using.  I simply used it as an example of a list-comprehension/generator expression for lack of a better example.

Comment: Fair enough. And, of course, it's valid to use that construct with "if" clauses to select specific elements (though `filter()` stands a chance of being faster).